# Filtro de filiais usando Buttons

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, aplicação-web

Olá,

Fiz um filtro de filiais para a minha empresa, porém empaquei em uma pendência.

Quero que a pessoa escolha a região da filial e navegue pelo conteúdo desse *button* e que o conteúdo desapareça, caso ela aperto o mesmo botão ou escolha outra região.

Código atual HTML:

```
<form style="display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;">
            <input id="button"type="button" class="cb" value="Sul" name="1" id="1" onclick="itemSelectS(this)" onblur="showDivAttidS(this)"/>
            <input id="button"type="button" class="cb" value="Sudeste" name="2" id="2" onclick="itemSelectSE(this)"  onblur="showDivAttidSE(this)"/>
            <input id="button"type="button" class="cb" value="Centro - Oeste" name="3" id="3" onclick="itemSelectCO(this)" onblur="showDivAttidCO(this)"/>
            <input id="button"type="button" class="cb" value="Norte / Nordeste" name="4" id="4" onclick="itemSelectNEN(this)" onblur="showDivAttidNEN(this)"/>
    </form>


 <div style="display:none" id="1">Nenhuma filial cadastrada!</div>
 <div style="display:none" id="2">Nenhuma filial cadastrada!</div>
 <div style="display:none" id="3">Nenhuma filial cadastrada!</div>
 <div style="display:none" id="4">Nenhuma filial cadastrada!</div>

<script src="main.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
    #button {
  background-color:rgba(110, 74, 74, 0.103);
  border-color: #415f78 ;
  border-width: 3px;
  width: 450px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#button[value]{
  color: #415f78;
}

#button:hover{
  background-color: #415f78;
  border-color: forestgreen;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s; 
  -moz-transition: .1s all;   
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.1s; 
  -ms-transition: .1s all;   
  -ms-transition-delay: 0.1s; 
  -o-transition: .1s all;   
  -o-transition-delay: 0.1s; 
  transition: .1s all;   
  transition-delay: 0.1s; 
}

#button[value]:hover{
  color: white;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s; 
  -moz-transition: .1s all;   
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.1s; 
  -ms-transition: .1s all;   
  -ms-transition-delay: 0.1s; 
  -o-transition: .1s all;   
  -o-transition-delay: 0.1s; 
  transition: .1s all;   
  transition-delay: 0.1s; 
}
```

JS:

```
    function itemSelectS() {
    document.getElementById('1').style.display = "block";
}
function itemSelectSE() {
    document.getElementById('2').style.display = "block";
}
function itemSelectCO() {
    document.getElementById('3').style.display = "block";
}
function itemSelectNEN() {
    document.getElementById('4').style.display = "block";
}

function showDivAttidS(){
    document.getElementById("1").style.display = 'none';

}
function showDivAttidSE(){
    document.getElementById("2").style.display = 'none';

}
function showDivAttidCO(){
    document.getElementById("3").style.display = 'none';

}
function showDivAttidNEN(){
    document.getElementById("4").style.display = 'none';

}
```

Do jeito que está, caso eu clique em algum link, ou qualquer coisa do conteúdo, ele desaparece como se tivesse fechado, devido ao **onblur**.Procurei por pessoas que tenham passado por algo parecido mas não encontrei a solução.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, não precisa repetir tantas funções. Com apenas 2 funções você consegue o que precisa.

Agora, não repita id's, é incorreto no HTML. Outra coisa, não use nomes de id's começando com número ([veja esta documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)).

Com isso, removi os id's dos buttons (não é necessário), pois você pode pegar o valor do `name` e passar como `id` de cada div.

Com apenas duas funções, uma para o click e outra para o blur, você consegue fazer tudo o que deseja de acordo como explicou:

```js
function itemSelect(e) {
   var el = document.getElementById(e.name); // pega o elemento
   // alterna entre "block" e "none"
   el.style.display = el.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";
}

function showDivAttid(){
   // oculta todas as divs
   var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".divs");
   for(var x=0; x < divs.length; x++){
      divs[x].style.display = 'none';
   }
}
```

```css
   #button {
  background-color:rgba(110, 74, 74, 0.103);
  border-color: #415f78 ;
  border-width: 3px;
  width: 450px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#button[value]{
  color: #415f78;
}

#button:hover{
  background-color: #415f78;
  border-color: forestgreen;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s; 
  -moz-transition: .1s all;   
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.1s; 
  -ms-transition: .1s all;   
  -ms-transition-delay: 0.1s; 
  -o-transition: .1s all;   
  -o-transition-delay: 0.1s; 
  transition: .1s all;   
  transition-delay: 0.1s; 
}

#button[value]:hover{
  color: white;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s; 
  -moz-transition: .1s all;   
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.1s; 
  -ms-transition: .1s all;   
  -ms-transition-delay: 0.1s; 
  -o-transition: .1s all;   
  -o-transition-delay: 0.1s; 
  transition: .1s all;   
  transition-delay: 0.1s; 
}
```

```html
<form style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
   <input id="button"type="button" class="cb" value="Sul" name="r1" onclick="itemSelect(this)" onblur="showDivAttid()"/>
   <input id="button"type="button" class="cb" value="Sudeste" name="r2" onclick="itemSelect(this)"  onblur="showDivAttid()"/>
   <input id="button"type="button" class="cb" value="Centro - Oeste" name="r3" onclick="itemSelect(this)" onblur="showDivAttid()"/>
   <input id="button"type="button" class="cb" value="Norte / Nordeste" name="r4" onclick="itemSelect(this)" onblur="showDivAttid()"/>
</form>

<div class="divs" style="display:none" id="r1">S: Nenhuma filial cadastrada!</div>
<div class="divs" style="display:none" id="r2">SE: Nenhuma filial cadastrada!</div>
<div class="divs" style="display:none" id="r3">CW: Nenhuma filial cadastrada!</div>
<div class="divs" style="display:none" id="r4">NE: Nenhuma filial cadastrada!</div>
```